# How to read a properties file into an associative array?

Tags: bash, shell-script, associative-array

I'd like to read the properties in a [properties file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) into an associative array. **How can I do it?**

Specifics on what to parse: hash and equal signs. Everything else is a bonus.

Properties file content example:

```
# comment
a=value-a
b=http://prefix.suffix:8080/?key=value
c=password_with\\backslash-and=equals
```

I'd like this bash associative array to be constructed out of that file:

```
 declare -A props='(
  [a]="value-a"
  [b]="http://prefix.suffix:8080/?key=value"
  [c]="password_with\\backslash-and=equals" )'
```

(expected output of `declare -p` on that associative array, note that `${props[c]}` contains only one backslash, `"\\"` is `'\'`).

Comment: augeas [has a property file lens](https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/blob/master/lenses/properties.aug) so using `augtool` to retrieve whatever values you're interested in was another possible. IMHO putting some sort of third party parsing logic into your script is usually better than cobbling together yourself. You might be able to find something that seems to work for the data you've seen so far but it's generally safer to use logic someone else has vetted. You'd definitely want to limit the lenses you load if you were going to use `augtool` in a bash script or something.

Comment: does it need to handle comments (of the form ! and #) as well as the key/value formats: key=value, key = value, key:value, and key value?

Comment: @jeff - I don't know. Most of the properties files I saw use equals for separation and hash for comments.

Comment: I try to ask questions that clarify the OP so that we can get good answers. If you link to an example properties file but only want to parse some of them, then you need to clarify that. In either case, I think you should import the linked properties file into your question so that we don't have to leave the site to determine the requirements.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, Q&A are for everybody, not just the OP, The OP may only need to deal with a very limited set of files, but the next person having a similar requirement may not. It's a good idea for the OP to clarify his exact requirements, but IMO, not having them is not ground for closing the question, so I'm requesting it being reopened.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, @StéphaneChazelas -- my main point was that AlikElzin-kilaka linked to a sample file but then "didn't know" what syntax they wanted to support. I don't personally care what syntax that is, just that this Question should be clear about it.

Comment: Alik - is this question focused on supporting only the simple "key=value" and "#"-for-comment syntax? I'd be happy to reopen the question if we can get a clear direction on the expected syntax.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - it was a mistake. Sorry. Put you addition in. I also added more specifics.

Answer (score 7):

Use a real parser like `perl`'s [`Config::Properties`](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Config%3A%3AProperties&mode=module) module. I would do the whole script in `perl`, but if you have to use `bash`, you could do something like:

```
typeset -A props
while IFS= read -rd '' key && IFS= read -rd '' value; do
  props[$key]=$value
done < <(
  perl -MConfig::Properties -l0 -e '
   $p = Config::Properties->new();
   $p->load(STDIN);
   print for $p->properties' < file.properties
)
```

(also works with `zsh`).

Implementing a full parser in `bash` would be a lot of work and mean re-inventing the wheel. You can implement a good subset with a simple `while read` loop though as the `read` builtin expects an input format that is very similar to those properties files:

```
typeset -A props
while IFS=$':= \t' read key value; do
  [[ $key = [#!]* ]] || [[ $key = "" ]] || props[$key]=$value
done < file.properties
```

(also works with `ksh93` and `zsh`, the two other Bourne-like shell supporting associative arrays).

That handles:

- `prop = value`
- `prop: value`
- `prop value`
- comments at the start of the line (`!` and `#` with optional leading blanks)
- backslash escaping (as in `foo\:\:bar=value` for keys containing delimiters or `foo=\ bar` or the `password_with\\backslash-and=equals` in your sample).
- line continuation with backslash

However, if we check against the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

- That doesn't handle `\n`, `\r`, `\uXXXX`... sequences
- LF is the only recognised line delimiter (not CR nor CRLF).
- FF is not recognised as a whitespace (we can't just add it to `$IFS` as depending on the shell and version, `\f` will not necessarily be recognised as an IFS-whitespace character¹).
- for an input like `foo: bar =` , that stores `bar` in `${props[foo]}` instead of `bar =`  (`foo: bar:baz:` is OK though). That's only a problem when the value of the property contains one (unescaped) delimiter (`:` optionally surrounded by SPC/TAB characters, `=` optionally surrounded by SPC/TAB characters or sequence of one or more SPC/TAB characters) and it is at the end.
- it treats as comments lines that start with `\!` or `\#`. Only a problem for properties whose name starts with `!` or `#`.
- in

  ```
    prop=1\
     2\
     3
  ```

we get `1 2 3` instead of `123`: the leading spaces are not ignored in the continuation lines as they should be.

---

<sup>² *IFS whitespace characters*, per POSIX are the characters classified as `[:space:]` in the locale (which generally includes `\f` but doesn't have to) and that happen to be in `$IFS` though in ksh88 (on which the POSIX specification is based) and in most shells, that's still limited to SPC, TAB and NL. The only POSIX compliant shell in that regard I found was `yash`. `ksh93` and `bash` (since 5.0) also include other whitespace (such as CR, FF, VT...), but limited to the single-byte ones (beware on some systems like Solaris, that includes the non-breaking-space which is single byte in some locales)</sup>

Comment: `Can't locate Config/Properties.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Config::Properties module)`. Missing perl module :(

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka, hence the link to where to find it in my answer. You can do `install Config::Properties` in `cpan`.

Comment: installing modules from CPAN isn't hard, but (depending on your unix or linux distribution) you may be able to install it even easier with your system's package manager.  e.g. on debian `apt-get install libconfig-properties-perl`.

Comment: @cas I'm not able to find this package in Ubuntu 16.04 Is there any alternative for this in Xenial ? https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/perl/

Comment: there are dozens of perl config file parsers.  `Config::Simple` (packaged as `libconfig-simple-perl`) will probably work with this file format.  See https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/perl/ for a list of all packaged perl modules in xenial, and search that page for `libconfig-`.

Comment: I searched over there and did not find the package which has Config::Properties. Currently, our code repo has packaged Properties.pm (due to previous environment constraint). I'm new to perl and trying to install the package in Ubuntu OS, rather than carrying having pm file in code repo. I could use other parsers, but, this needs lot of code refactoring. Please let me know which Ubuntu package has this file

Answer (score 6):

Here is howto in Bash4+

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A properties

# Read with:
# IFS (Field Separator) =
# -d (Record separator) newline
# first field before separator as k (key)
# second field after separator and reminder of record as v (value)
while IFS='=' read -d $'\n' -r k v; do
  # Skip lines starting with sharp
  # or lines containing only space or empty lines
  [[ "$k" =~ ^([[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*#.*)$ ]] && continue
  # Store key value into assoc array
  properties[$k]="$v"
  # stdin the properties file
done < file.properties

# display the array for testing
typeset -p properties
```

`file.properties`:

```bsh
# comment
a=value-a
b=http://prefix.suffix:8080/?key=value
c=password_with\\backslash-and=equals

d e=the d e value
  # comment
```

The output of this script from the supplied data sample:

```bsh
declare -A properties=(["d e"]="the d e value" [c]="password_with\\\\backslash-and=equals" [b]="http://prefix.suffix:8080/?key=value" [a]="value-a" )
```

Comment: This version worked for me with regular property files (NAME=API_KEY).
The version mentionned in this thread, where  ${line% =*} is the key : I couldn't reaccess the value via the array.

Comment: This is in my opinion the best answer. Simple and straightforward, using pure bash (perl is great, but the question wanted bash; plus this is easier to read unless you're really familiar with perl). Plus is skips comments and empty lines, which is a nice perk.

Answer (score 4):

For the most common subset of that dataformat, you can use a short function, using [bash variable expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) and regexp matching.

Note: This expects lines to be in `^key = value$` format, or `^#.*$` and `^!.*$` for comments. Adapt the code, or pre-process your data otherwise

```
$ cat /tmp/propdata 
k1 = v1
# A comment
k2 = v2and some s=t=u=f=f
! Another comment
k3 = v3

$ unset DATA
$ declare -A DATA

$ props(){ while read line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
[[ "$line" =~ ^#|^! ]] && continue;
if [[ "${line% =*}" ]]; then DATA[${line% =*}]="${line#*= }" ; fi ;
done < $1 ; }

$ props /tmp/propdata

$ echo "${DATA[k3]}"
v3
$ echo "${DATA[k2]}"
v2and some s=t=u=f=f
```

Edit: Updated to trim the spaces around the "=" for key and value

Edit2: Filters comments now too.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare -A properties
function readPopertyFile
{
    while read line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
        key=`echo $line | cut -s -d'=' -f1`
        if [ -n "$key" ]; then
            value=`echo $line | cut -d'=' -f2-`
            properties["$key"]="$value"
        fi
    done < $1
}
```

Usage:

```
readPopertyFile "file.properties"
```

Will read the properties into an associative array variable named `properties`.

* Works in bash. Don't know about other shells.

* Won't handle multi-line properties.

Comment: Using bash parameter expansion to set the variables  will save you 2 sub shells, 2 echo, 2 pipes and two cut commands with `key=${line%=*}` and  `value=${line#*=}`.  that's less clear but much faster if the file is big.

Comment: @Emmanuel - Will `${line#*=}` "eat" the whole value? Even when there are several `=` (equal) chars?

Comment: [Always double quote variable expansions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). Your script breaks on lines containing spaces and wildcards due to the missing double quotes. But as Emmanuel advises you should use parameter expansion instead of `echo | cut`, it's easier to get it right and faster. `${line#*=}` cuts off the part up to the first `=`, and `${line%%*=}` (note double `%`) cuts off the part from the first `=`.

Comment: I noted the `cut -s` that is followed by a test on empty strings. This is to deal with lines containing no "=". Parameter expansion will not help here but you can filter the input at the beginning of the script : `grep = $1 | while read line`. It adds one `grep` to the script but as it is outside the loop, that's ok.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka I assumed  values would not contain an =, if thats the case use the %% (longest matching string) as advised by  Giles.

Comment: Try on an input like `a=+ * +` or `a\=b=c` or `a=b    c` (3 spaces in between b and c, which SE apparently won't let me insert in a comment), `-nene=foo`